# Significance of bump function in the proof.

Tags: manifolds, tensors, vector-fields

In the book Semi-Riemannian Geometry with applications to Relativity by Barrett O'Neill, in Chapter 2 (Tensors), he stated that:
[image]

However, I don't get why he had to use a bump function in the proof. Wouldn't it be correct if he just said that since $X^i(p) = 0$ then the RHS (without bump function) will be zero?

I see that he imposed a bump function $f$ to say that $fX^i$ is smooth and $f \partial _i \in \frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$. But isn't $\partial _i \in \frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$ already?

What would fail in the proof had there been no bump function?

Comment: Because your operator $A$ is defined on all of $M$, so the bump function extends the use of the neighboorhood $\mathcal{U}$ to all of $M$ to allow us to use the operator $A$.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question has been given as a comment:

> Because your operator $A$ is defined on all of $M$, so the bump function extends the use of the neighboorhood $\mathcal{U}$ to all of $M$ to allow us to use the operator $A$. –  Chris Gerig Jan 24 at 8:13